# Can I disable Sunset Invasion after starting a game?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I started a game of CK2 a while ago, with all DLC enabled, I got my nice little Scandinavian Empire spilling a bit in Russia and England, the reformed Norse religion is strong and the Empire of Francia is the only power that really stand in my way.

Now, I said I started this game with all DLC enabled. This means that, sooner or later, the Aztecs will come knock on our doors to wipe us out. This is obviously not good for the empire.

What I would like is to know if I can disable the future invasion in a game that was already started. I suppose I would need to edit the save file, in fact, I already looked into it, but there is no obvious `b_aztec_invading = 1` or anything like this.

Comment: Disabling the DLC before they actually arrive should work. No idea what happens if they already showed up and you disable it.

Comment: You should disable the DLC in the game launcher and continue playing as normal. It should not cause any problems if Aztecs have not already showed up.

Comment: I'm curious. How did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special is required, just starting the game with the DLC disabled is enough to avoid having western Europe crushed by the American hordes.